# Хотел написать шифр цезаря но сдвиг по ключам работает неправильно

Tags: python

```
def m_encrypt(plaintext, key, final=""):
    for symbol in plaintext:
        final += chr((ord(symbol) + key - 13)%26 + ord('A'))
    return final.lower()

message = input("Enter the message: ")
message.lower()
e_key = int(input("Write the key: "))
print("Encrypted message:", m_encrypt(message, e_key))
```

Comment: Строка `message.lower()` не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def m_encrypt(plaintext, key, final=""):
    plaintext = plaintext.lower()
    for symbol in plaintext:
        final += chr((ord(symbol) + key - ord('a'))%26 + ord('a'))
    return final.lower()
```

Так работает

Ошибка была в том, что порядок английской `a` - 97, а не 13 (`A` - 65)